# If $f$ is one-to-one and continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$ then prove that $f$ is strictly monotone on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

> If $f$ is one-to-one and continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$ then prove that $f$ is strictly monotone on $[a,b]$.

So my plan was to prove this by contradiction.

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to prove this that I am missing. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $f(a)<f(b)$ we show that $f$ is strictly increasing.

Let $x\in [a,b]$ firstly, we show that $f(x)>f(a)$ if $f(x)\leq f(a)$, since $f$ is continuous, the image of $[x,b]$ by $f$ is an interval, since it contains $f(x)\leq f(a)$ and $f(b)>f(a)$ it contains every element $u$ such that $f(x)\leq u\leq f(b)$ in particular, there exists an element $z\in [x,b]$ such that $f(z)=f(a)$, since $a<x$ we have a contradiction since $f$ is bijective.

Suppose $f$ is not increasing, there exists $x,y\in [a,b] x<y, f(x)\geq f(y)$ if $f(x)=f(y)$ $f$ is not injective, done. Suppose $f(x)>f(y)$, since $f$ is continue, $f([a,x])$ is an interval, it contains every element $u$ such that $f(a)\leq u\leq f(x)$, in particular since $f(a)\leq f(y) <f(x)$ we deduce  that $[a,x]$  contains $z$ such that $f(z)=f(y)$, $z\leq x<y$ this is a contradiction since $f$ is bijective. done.

If $f(a)> f(b)$, the previous part shows that $-f$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: At the second paragraph the second sentence " in particular $f(a)\leq f(y)<f(x)$ " does it have to be $f(a)<f(y)$ ? Because it is already proved on the first paragraph that it can not be $f(a)=f(y)$ .